# Inserting a unix timestamp into MySQL from Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, timestamp

I'm looking to insert the current system timestamp into a field on a database. I don't want to use the server side `now()` function and need to use the python client's system timestamp. What MySQL datatype can store this value, and how should I insert it? Is `time.time()` sufficient?

Comment: i think it's a different question. 'm looking for a unix timestamp (more accuracy), not a daily datetime as shown in the examples you cited. also, still not sure what datatype to use on the db side to store this.

Comment: is there a reason not to use the DATETIME data type? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: "Is `time.time()` sufficient?" That's up to you to decide. So? Is it sufficient for your use case? If so, it's just a float value... store it as one.

Answer (score 1):

`time.time()` is a float, if a resolution of one second is enough you can just truncate it and store it as an INTEGER.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s")
'1403545051'
```

Comment: Not working in python 3.6

Comment: >>>int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())